# How can we implement tick rate on iOS?

Tags: networking, ios

I am really new to gaming development. For my multi-player game, I want to send my gaming update to the server 64 times per second. Is it a good idea to use `CADisplayLink` to do this?

If not, what is commonly used to implement this tick system on iOS?

Comment: Are you using a cross-platform development environment, or programming using the native Apple technologies? `CADisplayLink` belongs in the Core Animation class, which isn't directly related to networking.

Comment: @liggiorgio Hi, I saw a lot of discussion about tick rate but I am not sure who is supposed to send this network update every tick. If it's a cross platform game using Unity, is this functionality provided by Unity? I couldn't find it

Comment: Tick rate may refer to the number of updates/second in the game logic, in the rendering pipeline, and in other areas including the networking components. This is because multithreading allows decoupling of such modules, letting you have a display refresh rate of let's say 60 Hz, while updating the game logic at 30 Hz, and sending network updates only at 10 Hz because your game logic is able to conceal latency.

Comment: Unity, among many others, lets you define the rate of your game updates, screen refresh, and a per-gameObject network send rate. Important data is updated frequently, non-essential data is updated once in a while or only when needed. This is essential for computational balance, especially for mobile devices. You can find many questions under the [tag:networking] tag, or you can search more specific questions already covering similar topics.